# present a view controller modally, just like MFMailComposer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

When MFMailComposer shows in an app on iPad, it shows a partial screen view in landscape, with the screen underneath grayed out.

Is there a straightforward way to do this with a different view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's done as a regular modal view controller with a modal presentation style of either `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` or `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.